# Extjs - upload file using filefield

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, filefield

My extjs code like **http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.form.field.File.html**

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Upload a Photo',
    width: 400,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    frame: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),    
    items: [{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'photo',
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        labelWidth: 50,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '100%',
        buttonText: 'Select Photo...'
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Upload',
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if(form.isValid()){
                form.submit({
                    url: 'photo-upload.php',
                    waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                    success: function(fp, o) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

my photo-upload.php file

```
echo "{success:true}";
```

But when success **o.result.file** show **undefined**. I think it will show file name after success.

How can i make it show file name after success thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just returning `"{success:true}"` which is not even  valid JSON but expect ExtJS to provide you with even more data?

Try to return JSON like

```
{ "success": true, "file": "filename" }
```

so that there is a file property in the result that the client can read.

Comment: I did this: $result = array( 'success' => 'true', 'file' => 'filename.ext' );
   $x= json_encode($result); echo $x;

Answer (score 0):

just return proper json construction to eval in front end.

To display the file name as a message, u dont need to return value from backend, already it available with you. refer below code

var fileUploadComp =   // eg: Ext.getCmp('DictUploadField');
var fileName = fileUploadComp.getValue();

place this `fileName`  in your message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

​Note: server response type should be "text/html".

```
return Json(new {
    success = true,
    msg = "Your file has been uploaded"
}, "text/html");
```

Live demo is [here](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-upload-to-asp-net-mvc-demo.html)